# In HBase is there a way for me to get the middle key of a region?

Tags: hbase

It looks like I can get the middle key like so:

```
        RegionServerServices rss = null;
        final List<Region> onlineRegions = rss.getOnlineRegions(tableName);

        for (Region region : onlineRegions) {
            final List<Store> stores = region.getStores();
            for (Store store : stores) {
                final long storeSize = store.getSize();
                final byte[] splitPoint = store.getSplitPoint();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, there is no way for me to get an `HRegion` or a `Region` or a `RegionServerService` on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am not sure how safe this approach is, since it may put a read-lock on the hfile.  I am going to try to use it on snapshots so I'll be ok.*

Also you may wish to :

- get the midpoint of the store for a particular column family and
- get the midpoint of the largest store, that may give you a better approximation when your region has multiple stores

excuse the formatting....

```
    try (Connection connection = 
                ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hbaseConfig);
                Admin admin = connection.getAdmin();) {
    final List<HRegionInfo> regionInfoList = admin.getTableRegions(tableName);
    HRegionInfo regionInfo = regionInfoList.get(0);
    final HRegion region = HRegion.openHRegion(hbaseConfig,

    FileSystem.get(hbaseConfig),
                                                   new Path("/hbase"),
                                                   regionInfo,
                                                   table.getTableDescriptor(),
                                                   null,
                                                   null,
                                                   null);
     List<Store> stores = region.getStores();
     stores.get(0).getSplitPoint();
    }
```